# ArcPy runs slow outside ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, performance

I'm running a fairly small script to get height differences. The scripts gets the height in a point based on a DTM. Running the script in the ArcMap python window uses 1 min 30 seconds for 1000 points, while running it in the python window outside Arcmap (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe) uses 2 min 40 seconds for the same 1000 points. What causes this big difference? There can be many points for each dataset, so I want it to be able to run outside ArcMap so it doesn't run out if memory.

```py
import arcpy 
import datetime

arcpy.env.workspace =  r'\\path\Laserdata.gdb'
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace =  r'\\path\Temp_data.gdb'
# laserline 
laser = 'L0380_2m_Vertice_selection'

# 1 x 1 m raster
raster_1m = r'\\path\Connection to sde.sde\DTM1'

def main():
    i = 1
    print "Starttime: " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    fields = arcpy.ListFields(laser)

    if len(arcpy.ListFields(laser,"DTMZ"))>0:  
        print "Field exist"  
    else:  
        print "Does not exist"
        arcpy.AddField_management(laser, "DTMZ", "FLOAT")

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(laser, ['SHAPE@X','SHAPE@Y' ,'DTMZ']) as curs:
        for row in curs:
            X = str(row[0]).replace(".",",")
            Y = str(row[1]).replace(".",",")
            XY = str(X + " " + Y)

            hoydeDTM  = arcpy.GetCellValue_management(raster_1m, XY)
            if str(hoydeDTM) == 'NoData':
                hoydeDTM = -9999
            else:
                hoydeDTM = hoydeDTM

            row[2] = str(hoydeDTM)
            i = i + 1 
            if i % 1000 == 0:
                print i
                print datetime.datetime.now() - start
            curs.updateRow(row)

    print "Endtime: "  + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print  datetime.datetime.now() - start

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean that one process took 40 *seconds* or 40 *minutes* longer. You'd likely have better performance if your DEM was in a local GeoTIFF instead of an Enterprise geodatabase. I wouldn't expect to see performance or memory savings with a 32-bit Python.

Comment: A general piece of advice - move your raster out of ArcSDE geodatabase into a file geodatabase (best if local one, stored on your SSD drive). I guess the reason in performance difference is that you might have your raster added into ArcMap session so the `GetCellValue` operates faster on the raster layer in your map rather than connecting to the ArcSDE and reading the raster each time you run your `GetCellValue`. Depending on the size of your raster, you may boost the performance drastically by copying the raster into the special `in_memory` workspace once before going into `for` loop

Comment: `In_memory` http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm. Check whether your raster can fit into the RAM you have on your machine

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Thank you for the advice. The problem here is that the raster is huge. Its uncompressed size is 5,72 TB and covers a whole country. I will check if I can clip out parts of it to use for the analysis and add it to the FGDB.

Comment: @Vince I tried using ArcGIS Pro, but I got aproximatly the same time as using python outside ArcMap, which I found kind of weird.

Comment: There is a 64-bit Python for ArcMap (Background Geoprocessing). I wouldn't expect it to be any faster. arcpy is a *huge* library; it takes time to wrap all the objects on `import`. That time is hidden during ArcMap setup, but in a standalone Python it sticks out.

Comment: When you say its faster when run in ArcMap -- is the raster a layer in your ToC when running the script in the PyWindow? If so, that's a huge part right there compared to outside the app. ArcMap already has the raster loaded. The entire script execution time is almost always faster to process something thats open vs. having the process need to open the file first (like what needs to happen from a script outside arcmap)

Comment: @KHibma Yes. I still find it weird that the difference is so big. Would it not load once in the script or does it need to load every time I run the process?

Comment: Running a script is a singular process. You may have your script editor (IDE) open, but that doesn't keep the raster loaded. Every time you execute the script new, it needs to go fetch/open the raster. When doing "performance tests" or simple compares, its better to do them on individual tool or small part of the workflow. Comparing the execution of something inside ArcMap to a complete script execution isn't an apples-apples compare.

Comment: @KHibma I understand, but I tried to run for 36 000 points and taking the time. It uses much more time between every 1000nd than inside arcmap. I can't really wrap my head around it. I also tried it in python 3 for Pro now on my C disk and it used 20 sec per 10th calculation, which is incredible slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AlexTereshenkov idea that it could be down to it being a layer may be the source of this problem, if you look at the help file for the Get Cell Value Tool what does the [Syntax section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/get-cell-value.htm#GUID-F09D60C8-61EA-4A0C-971F-DFF424E8C86C) tell you that it wants as input? A raster *layer*, you are not providing it with a layer but a string which is the full path to a raster *dataset*. I would imagine internally it is having to convert that to a layer object on every cycle of the loop.

That being said you have written a whole load of unnecessary code which can all be done in just one tool! I suggest you explore the [Extract Values to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) tool? I would expect this to be much faster as it is a system tool (compiled code).

Comment: The extract values to point tools was so much faster. Thank you for showing me.

Comment: @birks good news! Glad that has worked, out of interest how fast?

Comment: Also get into the habit of reading the help file syntax section to understand what the inputs are, layers and datasets may look like the same thing but they are very different beasts (for good reasons).

Comment: I think it was something like a minute for the whole 36 k points!